# SIGABRT caused by arrays

Tags: objective-c, arrays, memory

When I click the button for nextIdea(), I get an error that highlights `int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil)` and says SIGABRT

```
- (IBAction)nextIdea:(id)sender
{
int index = arc4random() % ideaArray.count;
ideaTextView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[ideaArray objectAtIndex:index]];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Ideas"];
[query whereKey:@"Hidden" equalTo:@"entry"];
[query getObjectWithId:@"Idea"];
ideaArray = [[[NSArray alloc] init] autorelease];
//  ideaArray = [query findObjects];
ideaArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"one", @"two", nil];
}
```

I've been trying to figure this out for hours but have no luck.

ideaArray is declared in the header and synthesized btw

Exact error message:

```
[15842:f803] application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3010 "remote notifications are not supported in the simulator" UserInfo=0x6a5e500 {NSLocalizedDescription=remote notifications are not supported in the simulator}
```

When on the device, error reads:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3000 "no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application" UserInfo=0x19f4f0 {NSLocalizedDescription=no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application}
```

Comment: Where in your code do you release the array?  Do you Dealloc it?  Because that would be wrong.   Usually retVal indicates a call to a nil object.

Comment: I don't, when I did release it in -dealloc, it gave me EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Without releasing it gives me SIGABRT

Comment: What does the SIGABRT say?  Deallocing an auto released object is a no-no.

Comment: I just added in the error message. I also tried doing it without autorelease, but that didn't work either.

Comment: The error is exactly what it says.  In order to use APN notifications, one must test on a physical device.  Sorry, but all I can say is comment out your APN service code until you have a test device.

Comment: It stills errs when on the device

Comment: For the device error, check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681172/bundle-identifier-and-push-certificate-aps-environment-entitlement-error (this is my final post, I do not wish to extend the comments section any further.  Good luck)

Comment: Are you sure that it has nothing to do with the allocation? If you don't use `self` during allocation (in the viewDidLoad), you can't really access it from the `nextIdea:` method. Can you just try using `self.ideasArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"one", @"two", nil];` ?

Comment: I did try that, it returns with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property was set to (nonatomic, assign), just changed assign to copy, and it works

Answer (score 0):

Unless you store the `ideaArray` as a class variable, you will not be able to access it from the `nextIdea:` method.

1. Make the `ideaArray` a [property](http://cocoacast.com/?q=node/103) of the class.
2. When you allocate the array, use the `self.ideaArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"one", @"two", nil];` notation. The self will refer to the property you have created.
3. Access the array from the `nextIdea:` method using `self.ideaArray`.