# Code Sign error when using cocos2D

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I have purchased a developer account from Apple. By taking development provisions, I have tested example app in device. Then I have downloaded `cocos2d-iphone-1.0.1` and set it up. Then I created a project called `FirstGame`. When I compile sample cocos2D project on device, it gives this error:

> Code Sign error: A valid provisioning profile matching the application's Identifier 'com.yourcompany.FirstGame' could not be found

In the build settings of project, the development profiles are not enabled. I am using Xcode 4.6.

[image]

**Edit:** I've found solution applying [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3729200/2111065) solution.:

Comment: @erkanyildiz: Even if the problem isn’t actually caused by cocos2D, it apparently works before cocos2D and not after. It’s not really correct (?) to tag the question based on the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with cocos2d. Just edit the bundle identifier of the project, and make sure you have correct provisioning profiles.

It should be **com.ahmetatalay.FirstGame**, not **com.yourcompany.FirstGame** which is default in cocos2d template.

Change it under Project Settings section of Xcode, to code sign it with your wildcard profile or the profile you created specifically for it.

See Apple's documentation for details:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/DevPortalGuide/CreatingandDownloadingDevelopmentProvisioningProfiles/CreatingandDownloadingDevelopmentProvisioningProfiles.html

Comment: Thanks, I have changed the identifier from "info.plist".

Comment: Alternatively, create a wildcard profile (i.e. with bundle identifier set to just `*`). The automatically-generated "Xcode Team Provisioning Profile" does this.